# Планирую реализовать шифрование RSA на Java с получением открытого ключа от сервера на php. Как лучше сделать?

Tags: php, java, rsa

Планирую реализовать шифрование RSA на Java с получением открытого ключа от сервера на php. Как лучше передавать ключ, где хранить закрытый ключ и можно ли генерировать каждый раз одинаковую пару ключей?

Comment: Можете енд-ту-енд юзкейс привести (конкретный пример использования ключей)? Не очень понятно что именно Вы планируете реализовать.

Comment: Как лучше сделать — зависит от того, что именно нужно сделать. Плюс нужно иметь серьёзную причину работать с RSA напрямую вместо использования готовых инструментов безопасности

Comment: Хочу чтобы приложение на Java получало открытый ключ от сервера, шифровало данные, и передавало данные на сервер, а сервер сохранял закрытый ключ, чтобы в будущем можно было расшифровывать данные при необходимости.

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что RSA не позволяет зашифровать данные больше килобайта?

Comment: Да, объем данных у меня не такой большой.

Comment: В общем генерировать каждый раз ключи не надо. Даже не то, что не надо, а нельзя, если Вы не хотите свистопляски с уровнем доверия к Вашим ключам. Нужна одна пара, при том, что публичный ключ должен быть обернут в сертификат. Хранить закрытый ключ надо (очевидно) на севре. Например в сторе формата pkcs12: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7292

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.